# Merge to Insert or update records in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, biztalk

I am having hard time with creating a stored procedure to insert/update the selected records from an Oracle database to a SQL Server database using BizTalk.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateINF]
    @dp_id                char(32),
    @dv_id                char(32),
    @em_number            char(12),
    @email                varchar(50),
    @emergency_relation   char(32),
    @option1              char(16),
    @status               char(20),
    @em_id                char(35),
    @em_title             varchar(64),
    @date_hired           datetime
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   MERGE [dbo].[em] AS [Targ]
   USING (VALUES (@dp_id, @dv_id , @em_number, @email, @emergency_relation, @option1, @status, @em_id, @em_title, @date_hired))
   AS [Sourc] (dp_id, dv_id, em_number, email, emergency_relation, option1, status, em_id, em_title, date_hired)  
      ON [Targ].em_id = [Sourc].em_id

   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE 
         SET dp_id                 = [Sourc].dp_id,
             dv_id                 = [Sourc].dv_id,
             em_number             = [Sourc].em_number,
             email                 = [Sourc].email,
             emergency_relation    = [Sourc].emergency_relation,
             option1               = [Sourc].option1,
             status                = [Sourc].status,
             em_title              = [Sourc].em_title,
             date_hired            = [Sourc].date_hired

   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
      INSERT (dp_id, dv_id, em_number, email, emergency_relation, option1, status, em_id, em_title,date_hired)
      VALUES ([Sourc].dp_id, [Sourc].dv_id, [Sourc].em_number, [Sourc].email, [Sourc].emergency_relation, [Sourc].option1, [Sourc].status, [Sourc].em_id, [Sourc].em_title, [Sourc].date_hired);

 END;
```

I am getting an error:

> WcfSendPort_SqlAdapterBinding_TypedProcedures_dbo_Custom" with URL "mssql://abc//def?". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'uspInsertorUpdateINF' expects parameter '@dp_id', which was not supplied

I am mapping the values from the Oracle DB to SQL Server stored procedures using BizTalk maps

[image]

I am not sure why I get this error.

Comment: Pelase check if there is any record in source table that has empty column HOME_AU (that is mapped to dp_id argument of sp).

Comment: Might want to take a peek at this before you settle on using MERGE. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure isn't getting the @dp_id parameter.  The most likely cause of this is that the HOME_AU in the source message is empty/nil.  You can check this several ways:

1. The Group Hub tab, query Suspended Instances, check the suspended instance's message, look for the value of the dp_id node
2. Turn on message tracking for the port(s)/orchestration(s) that process this message, and look in Tracked Message Events; this would show you successful messages (if there are any) as well, and may give you the source message.
3. Use SQL Server Profiler to check the actual procedure call, and check the value of the parameter that's getting passed as @dp_id.  This could be used to diagnose a problem if you're not seeing anything unusual about HOME_AU/dp_id in in the XML.

Your most likely cause of this is the source data having a null or empty value for whatever is producing HOME_AU.  If that's the case, you can specify `@dp_id char(30)  = NULL`, or whatever default value you want it to have in your stored procedure definition.

Also, FYI - you will generally get better performance (and greater flexibility) using Table Valued Parameters in your stored procedures from BizTalk.  Especially since, in this case, you're trying to build a table out of the parameters (using a VALUES clause) in your procedure anyway.

Comment: It really helped to solve the issue, The Oracle DB was having NULL value for the dp_id and after we changed that it worked. But it just inserts only one record from the Oracle to SQL DB. Why doesn't it select select the entire set of records do an Insert or update.

Comment: To do that you'd need to pass a table varaible - which could contain multiple rows.  You're effectively passing a single row at a time.

Comment: How I do pass table variables, I am new to SQL database queries and stored procedures. Can you please explain in little detail.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx - and then just generate a new schema for the table valued version.  Then use a looping functoid on the repeating node to generate multiple rows in your table parameter.

Comment: Do I have to create a Table in SQL database. Can't I do anything in Biztalk end?

Comment: Create a TABLE TYPE.  The link I posted has an example.